# Installation and badge issue with Parse.com and ios

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I use installation, push and badge on my ios app (parse.com sdk 1.7.2.2)
and I noticed something few days ago,
the code that reset the badge to 0 as explained in the blog post (old one http://blog.parse.com/announcements/badge-management-for-ios/)

```
// Clear badge if needed
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
    currentInstallation.badge = 0;
    [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!succeeded) [ErrorHandler handle:@"save installation failed" forError:error];
    }];
}
```

does not work anymore, 
everything is good (no Parse error) but the badge count stay to the old value in the database

In a second time I tried the hard way, and it seems to work better for a moment:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

if (UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber > 0 || currentInstallation.badge > 0) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    currentInstallation.badge = 0;
    [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!succeeded) [ErrorHandler handle:@"save installation failed" forError:error];
    }];
}
```

But this is not working,
any idea?

Comment: But this code will save an installation value to your Parse table, even if the user has declined Push Notifications? Should you check if the user has an installation first?

Answer (score 3):

Heres my swift code and it works:

```
    // Resets badge number in parse
    var installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    if installation.badge != 0 {
        installation.badge = 0
        installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
    }

    // Resets badge number in app
    if application.applicationIconBadgeNumber > 0 {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't work in this order but I changed the order to be the applicationIconBadgeNumber reseted first then the parse installation and it worked. thx

Comment: that sounds really weird. do you have any idea why it works when the order is changed? they are unrelated codes when you look at it

Comment: It is related, I read somewhere on parse.com that acting on installation.badge triggers code on the ios "core" (shared application I guess) to reset the counter, maybe that part broke so I need to set it to zero first and then change the installation object?

Comment: It worked for a while and now that failed again, I updated my question

Comment: how is that even possible?

Comment: This code does not first check to see if the user actually has an Installation. What happens if the user declined Push Notifications, thus should not have an installation? In this case, you're still save a row in the Parse table..

Comment: It doesn't crash. I dont remember what it returned if the user did not have an installation, but you can easily check it out. This case worked perfectly for me, but we moved on from parse.

Answer (score 1):

there seems to be a dependency between the installation.badge and the application.applicationIconBadgeNumber setters. Ensuring the installation is always set first seems to alleviate the issue.

```
let pcur = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        print("current badge = \(pcur.badge)")
        if (pcur.badge != 0){
            pcur.badge = 0
            pcur.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (succeeded,error) in
                print("badge save success = \(succeeded)")
                application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Parse (1.14.2), Xcode 8, and ios 10, adding:

```
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

inside the **applicationDidBecomeActive** method in the **AppDelegate** class will also reset the **badge** on the parse server to zero.